# How to get cpu/memory usage from command line output

Tags: macos, mac

I am writing a program to read cpu and memory statistics from a remote host. The remote host can be Linux or Mac. So I need a command which returns the cpu/memory usage as output. I have found the command for Linux which is `vmstat`. But I couldn't find a good one for Mac. I know there is one command `vm_stat` on mac but it only returns memory usage. Is there a command for CPU usage as well? I have searched that most people use `top`. But top is good at monitoring and it would be hard to parse the result if I analyze its output in my program. I want to use one shipped with MacOS not a third party library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking to capture the total utilized CPU and Memory for all process, you could use this command that is native to Macs:

```
ps -A -o %cpu,%mem | awk '{ cpu += $1; mem += $2} END {print cpu , mem}'
```

Comment: Great answer! Also, if you want a some labels on the output, you can change it to `{print "CPU: "cpu"% MEM: "mem"%"}`. That will print something like `CPU: 16.3% MEM: 75.1%`

Comment: From the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) for ps command "CPU usage is currently expressed as the percentage of time spent running during the entire lifetime of a process.  This is not ideal, and it does not conform to the standards that ps otherwise conforms to.  CPU usage is unlikely to add up to exactly 100%." I don't think this will be matching instantaneous CPU that the poster seems to be asking for

Comment: This works great, THANK YOU. There are a lot of answers but this one worked great for Memory Usage.